# Laravel 4: Where is the Developer Log? Do I need a composer package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am just starting with Laravel 4, and came across a Laravel 3 example application on github...

This application has a wonderful developer log in the footer of the application.

Does Laravel 4 have such functionality? Any recommended composer packages?

[image: Laravel 3 Developer Log]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LOG` class for logging as other answer mentioned and a profiler is coming up soon but yes, there is a [Profiler package on github](https://github.com/loic-sharma/profiler) (A PHP 5.3 profiler based off of Laravel 3's [Anbu](https://github.com/daylerees/laravel-anbu)), you may install it using `composer`  or download it directly. here are some examples from `github`

```
Profiler::startTimer('testLogging');
// The profiler listens to Laravel's logger.
Log::info('Hello World!');
Log::notice('Some event occured.');

Profiler::endTimer('testLogging');
```

You may give it a try, could be helpful, also [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232512/how-to-use-laravel-4-profiler-correctly) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, it seems that a profiler is coming to us, sooner or later. :)

But there are some thing you can do to help you:

-Log files are in app/storage/logs

-You can use Log class to write your debugging to the log:

```
Log::info($sql);
```

-You can show SQL queries, by listening DB:

```
DB::listen(function($sql, $bindings, $time)
{
    Log::info($sql);
});
```

**EDIT:**

After look at Sheikh Heera's, found another profiler package for Laravel that looks pretty good too: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar.